# null JavaCompiler in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I am getting some errors with my Java Compiler. I am not getting errors outside of Eclipse, but it only seems to happen in Eclipse Indigo. This is not necessary, but if you have the answer, I would really appreciate it, as it would help me debug, and test the resources easier.

Thank you for reading this.

E: The ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returns null.

E2: [image]

Comment: can you post the detail error message or screenshot ?

Comment: Well, it is exactly how it is in the title.

The Toolprovider.getSystemJavaCompiler() returns null

Comment: Try checking  Java compiler  from preference

Comment: I posted a picture, they all appear the be the default values and all checked. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Go to **Java**->**Installed JREs**.  Add your JDK as a runtime.  You may choose to select this JDK to use for all your FUTURE projects.  However your selection will not take effect on existing projects.  Hence onto step 2.
2. Select your project's properties.  Select **Java Build Path**.
3. Under the **Libraries** tab, select JRE System Library [jreblahblahblah] and **Edit** it.
4. Select **Alternate JRE** and use the dropdown to find the JDK that you just added.
5. Clean your project and rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

> It happens when you use the JRE as Standard VM in Eclipse. Please use the JDK as Standard VM. It will work then.

Have a look at [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6477844).

For more information in setting the java VM see [Running Eclipse#Setting the java VM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm)

Comment: I added:
-vm
C:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin

To eclipse.ini, it still causes the NullPointer. Any other tips?

Oh, and I made sure those lines were above the -vmargs command

Comment: I tried javaw.exe, and java.exe

Thanks for your help, this is getting tough :/

Comment: The one thing I've noticed differently is a CMD window now appears at boot for eclipse.