# How to obtain the right JavaFileManager in a Java annotation processor?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotation-processing

I've written an Java annotation processor by extending `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor` which is called in the Eclipse context and it works fine, except that I need more information about the source path and class path for my processor to work:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"MyAnno"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class Processor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        // this used to work in Java4 but not anymore (since Java6?):
        String sourcePath = processingEnv.getOptions().get("sourcepath");
        String classPath = processingEnv.getOptions().get("classpath");

        for (Element e : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnno.class)) {
            myProcess(e, sourcePath, classPath); 
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The question is how to retrieve in the annotation processing context (the implementation of `process`) a valid `JavaFileManager` which can give me the source path and the classpath of the compiler which is currently executing the annotation processor. Preferably, I would find out about a solution which does not involve a dependency on Eclipse/JDT specific interfaces.

I've tried the following which does *not* work:

```
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics =
                   new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager fm = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler().getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
fm.getLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH); // prints an empty class path
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494596/eclipse-annotation-processor-get-project-path

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102444/cannot-load-resources-in-annotation-processor-not-on-classpath

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192381/how-can-i-get-the-working-directory-of-a-project-from-an-annotation-processor-in?rq=1

Comment: Would also be nice to understand why this isn't possible anymore.

Comment: Have you found a way to access the resources from the processor class?

Comment: Not like this question proposes. I made a separate and hacky mvn plug-in and eclipse plug-in. Not happy with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8 and before:

```java
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context;
import javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment;

    protected static JavaFileManager getJavaFileManager(ProcessingEnvironment env) {
        JavaFileManager fm = null;

        if (env instanceof JavacProcessingEnvironment) {
            Context context = ((JavacProcessingEnvironment) env).getContext();

            fm = context.get(JavaFileManager.class);
        }

        return fm;
    }
```

For Java 9 and 10 and later (and 8), use reflection to avoid tickling this
[bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209058):

```java
    protected static JavaFileManager getJavaFileManager(ProcessingEnvironment env) {
        JavaFileManager fm = null;

        try {
            /*
             * Context context = ((JavacProcessingEnvironment) env).getContext();
             */
            Method getContext = env.getClass().getMethod("getContext");
            Object context = getContext.invoke(env);
            /*
             * fm = context.get(JavaFileManager.class);
             */
            Method get = context.getClass().getMethod("get", Class.class);

            fm = (JavaFileManager) get.invoke(context, JavaFileManager.class);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }

        return fm;
    }
```